# Having trouble with adding home screen icons to create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

In `manifest.json` many sizes example

```
    { “src”:”images/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png”,
    “type”: “image/png”,
    “sizes”: “57x57”,
    }
```

in `index.html` links look like this

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=“%PUBLIC_URL%images/icons/apple- 
    icon-57x57.png" sizes="57x57" />
```

The icon files are in `public/images/icons`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but it might help others; you don't need a self-closing link tag because your `index.html` isn't a JSX file.

So `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href=“%PUBLIC_URL%images/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Icon**

When a user adds your site to their home screen, you can define a set of icons for the browser to use. These icons are used in places like the home screen, app launcher, task switcher, splash screen, etc.

icons is an array of image objects, each object should include the src, a sizes property, and the type of image.

for more information, just click [here](https://www.reactpwa.com/docs/en/web-app-manifest.html#scope)